# Logic Apps + Form Recognizer unable to send PDF to service

Tags: binary, base64, azure-logic-apps, azure-form-recognizer

I have an Azure Logic App that uses a `Analyze Document for Prebuilt or Custom models (v3.0 API)` action. The Custom Model is good, I can hit it with Postman with no issue.

When I try to get a PDF from Sharepoint and send it to the service, I get an error saying:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidRequest",
    "message": "Invalid request.",
    "innererror": {
      "code": "InvalidContent",
      "message": "The file is corrupted or format is unsupported. Refer to documentation for the list of supported formats."
    }
  }
}
```

**I've tried:**

- Passing the `Get file content` directly to the `Document/Image File Content` input
- Passing `body('Get_file_content)['$content']`
- Passing `concat('data:application/pdf;base64,',body('Get_file_content')['$content']`

  - This one converts to PDF in a Base64-to-PDF tool so I know the Base64 is good
- Then I found out that the service wants binary format:

  - Passing `base64ToBinary(body('Get_file_content')['$content'])`
  - Still no go

Why can I not send the file to the Form Recognizer service?

[image]

---

**EDIT:**

Thank you to @vijaya. They helped me see that the `Document/Image URL` parameter was not necessary. Leaving that blank and using the original `Get File Content` worked!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Issue is with content-type. You need to pass content-type along with content for analyze document. I have reproduced issue from my side and below are steps I followed,

1. Initially created logic app as shown below,
   [image]
2. Logic app failed with error,
   `The file is corrupted or format is unsupported. Refer to documentation for the list of supported formats.`
   [image]
3. Next modified logic app as shown below,
   [image]
4. In Compose action setting content as
   **outputs('Get_blob_content_(V2)')?['body']?['$content']** and passing content-type as application/pdf as we are dealing with pdf files.
   [image]
5. In Analyze Document for Prebuilt or Custom models (v3.0 API) action, using outputs of compose in Document/Image File Content.

[image]

6. Logic app ran successfully as shown below,

[image]
Output of Analyze Document is as shown below,
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. I tried the additional Compose action but I wasn't successful. Do you know what it was in the end? It was the `Document/Image URL`! I saw that you left that value out. I too left it out and used the original `Get File Content` output and it worked!

Comment: Is this solution working for you? In Document/Image URL I have not given any value as it is not mandatory field

Comment: I did try your suggestion, but it resulted in the same error. All I had to do was stop supplying a value for the `Document/Image URL`! That was giving me the error! Once removing this field, I was able to use the original `Get File Content` without anything else required.